# Where to put custom view templates in MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, t4

I want to create a replacement T4 template that can be called from Visual Studio's "add view". Where should I put the file? I'm not sure I should put it in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\
    Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\Web\
    MVC 3\CodeTemplates\AddView\VBHTML
```

I suspect it will get wiped during repair etc if I put it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your custom T4 template under your project like this:

```
{YourProjectFolder}\CodeTemplates\AddView
```

Of course this way it will only be enabled for this specific project, while putting them in the location you mention in your question will enable it for all your projects system wide.

Here you can find an interesting article going further into the details:

> [T4 Templates: A Quick-Start Guide for ASP.NET MVC Developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/01/29/t4-templates-a-quick-start-guide-for-asp-net-mvc-developers.aspx)

There's even already a nuget package who does all the plumbing for you:

> [Add the ASP.NET MVC 3 Code Templates to your application with Nuget](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joecar/archive/2011/01/06/add-the-asp-net-mvc-3-code-templates-to-your-application-with-nuget.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible locations. Either the one you showed which will be global for all projects on the system or in `~\CodeTemplates\AddView\VBHTML\MyTemplate.tt` if you want this template to be available only for a given project. Here's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joecar/archive/2011/01/06/add-the-asp-net-mvc-3-code-templates-to-your-application-with-nuget.aspx) about it.

Answer (score 1):

create the following structure in the ROOT of your Project (Not solution):
CodeTemplates\AddView\VBHTML (in your case, or CSHTML for C# razor views) and copy the templates from that folder into the newly created VBHTML folder.

Also in set the Tool property in the files' Property to empty, otherwise it will ask to build the *.tt file every time you save. Also consider using Tangible T4 Editor extension for Visual Studio to edit the templates. It's available on http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/